# PHP regular expressions: OR statements containing quantifiers

Tags: php, regex

Why does `an?|the` not work? I'm using PHP's preg_match().

Here's the full regex: `"/^an?|the (.+?) (is|was) an? (.+?)$/"`.

I want it to match `"the mona lisa is a painting"` and `"a dog is an animal"`.

It was working fine until I added in the `|the` to accommodate the first string example.

Thanks!

Comment: Hrmm, I suspect there needs to be `()` around it.

Comment: Ah. But then it becomes part of the $matches array - which is very inconvenient for me. Any possible workaround?

Comment: Non storing parenthesis (the proper name escapes me): `(?:an?|the)`

Comment: @Corbin: non-capturing back references :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote it it either matches using

```
^an?
```

or

```
the (.+?) (is|was) an? (.+?)$
```

which is obviously not what you want. You have to put it in parantheses the way you did it with `is|was`:

```
/^(an?|the) (.+?) (is|was) an? (.+?)$/
```

To prevent a group from being included in the result, use a non-matching group which syntax is `(?: )`. So just use it like this:

```
/^(?:an?|the) (.+?) (is|was) an? (.+?)$/
```